# How to store API requests in database using Flask and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to store my API request data in my database. I am looking for certain fields from the request namely the URL, REMOTE_ADDR to be stored in the database. I am using flask and sqlalchemy for my api and database connections to mysql database. Any help would be appreciated.

I have created a Log model to have the id, url, remote_addr fields to be stored in the database and I have written a function to read the request and map it into the model. I do not know where I am incorrect while trying to achieve this. I am including my app.py, log.py, loggerapi.py.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, send_from_directory
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from test import test_api
from usersapi import users_api
from authusersapi import authusers_api
from loggerapi import create_log
from database.db import db_uri

from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

import os

# Init app
app = Flask(__name__)

# config
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = db_uri
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = False

# Init db
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.create_all()

# Init ma
ma = Marshmallow(app)

# add urls
app.register_blueprint(test_api, url_prefix='/test')
app.register_blueprint(users_api, url_prefix='/users')
app.register_blueprint(authusers_api, url_prefix='/auth_users')

# logging
@app.before_request
def log_requests():
    create_log()

# Run the server
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),
                               'favicon.ico')
```

Log.py(model)

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

from datetime import datetime
import socket

db = SQLAlchemy()
ma = Marshmallow()

class Log(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String(100))
    remote_addr = db.Column(db.String(100))
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow) # the current timestamp

    def __init__(self, url, remote_addr):
        self.url = url
        self.remote_addr = remote_addr
        
class LogSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('url', 'remote_addr', 'created_at')
```

loggerapi.py(the function which creates the log and commits it into db)

```
from flask import request

from database.db import session_scope

from Models.Log import Log, LogSchema

log_schema = LogSchema(strict=True)
logs_schema = LogSchema(many=True, strict=True)

def create_log():
    with session_scope() as session:
        url = request.url
        remote_addr = request.remote_addr

        new_log = Log(url, remote_addr)
        
        print(new_log)
        session.add(new_log)
        session.commit()

        return log_schema.jsonify(new_log)
```

Actual results: No data in the 'Log' table

Expected results: Data in the 'Log' table

## **Update:**

## I have figured out that I had missed out the logic to use the before_request feature from flask. I have updated the code accordingly. Thanks Iguananaut.

Comment: It doesn't look like you actually *do* anything with `create_log` or call it anywhere? Did you intend to? Maybe register it with `app.before_request`?

Comment: @Iguananaut can you put in a sample code or a small example on top of my code for before_request? I am new to flask and I think I might have missed using the before_request

Comment: @ Iguananaut I think I figured it out. Please find the updated code above and let me know if that is the right way to do it wrt security and efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added this block to the code to app.py to actually use before_request.

```
@app.before_request
def log_requests():
    create_log()
```